# using a property without an object qualifier

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel's VBA there are some properties which I can use without an object qualifier - for instance if I use the property ActiveCell without an object qualifier it is as if I used it on the Application object. How is it, generally, decided on which object a property is called if I don't specify an object qualifier? Can I, for instance, do something similar with my own class? Can I declare in my own class a property which can be called without an object qualifier?

Comment: I think Application is the only default object.  Pretty sure you can't create one.  But I'd be interested to hear differently...

Comment: You may have better chance if you can make yourself a .dll and add it to the References. For example the object `VBIDE.` will not have drop down list if you don't have the Reference `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility` added. Just a thought...

Answer (score 2):

In VBA, a module or class is considered to inherit from the `Application`, then the object to which it is attached (a `userform`, `worksheet`, or `ThisWorkbook`), then itself.  Also, if a procedure name is unambiguous, then it isn't usually necessary to qualify it when you use it.

You can reference `Application.ActiveCell` as just `ActiveCell`, unless your class or module also contains an `ActiveCell` method, in which case you'd need to qualify it with `Application.`.

This also means that if you have `MyProc` as a member of `MyModule`, you can refer to it from another code/module file as just `MyProc`, but if you also have `MyProc` in `MyOtherModule`, then if you typed `MyProc`, it would call `MyModule.MyProc` if it was in `MyModule`, or `MyOtherModule.MyProc` if it was in `MyOtherModule`, otherwise it would raise an error stating that it was ambiguous, meaning that you'd have to qualify it to `MyModule.MyProc` or `MyOtherModule.MyProc`.

However...

A class module defines the internal workings of a class, and a class must be instantiated before it can be used with `New`.  A class's properties refer to a specific instance of a class, so must always be qualified with the instance to which it refers.  I.e. if you have a class `MyClass` with a string property `MyProperty`, you would have to call `MyProperty` via an instance, e.g.:

```
Set MyClassInstance = New MyClass
Debug.Print MyClassInstance.MyProperty()
```

or even:

```
Debug.Print (New MyClass).MyProperty()
```

The only way to avoid typing the name of a class instance is to declare a `With` block:

```
Set MyClassInstance = New MyClass
With MyClassInstance 
    Debug.Print .MyProperty()
End With
```

Comment: Regarding: "In VBA, a module or class is considered to inherit from the Application, then the object to which it is attached, then itself" I have two questions:
1. Is it general feature of Visual Basic or a specific feature of VBA?
2. Is it documented somewhere, in some official Microsoft documentation?